# My JavaScript code is not responding! I cannot see the changes on my website despite adding js codes

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server

I am working on a HTML/CSS and JavaScript website. I had no trouble linking my CSS sheet but I'm having trouble linking my  Js file with the html.

Here is how I linked my main.js with my index.html:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

I have tried refreshing the browser as well as using other browsers but nothing seems to be working

Comment: What does your code do?

Comment: Is the path correct? What is the exact problem? Check whether you get any error in the console.

Comment: @Omollo Felix We won't be able to help you unless you tell us what you did and what problem exactly are you facing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the .js file itself? index.html file structure? If you don't share your code it's quite difficult to argue what can be wrong